# pass function by reference

Tags: php

Well, I know what references are and when it's use is obvious.

One thing I really can't get is that when it's better to pass function by reference.

```
<?php

//right here, I wonder why and when
function &test(){

}
```

To avoid confusion, there're some examples as how I understand the references,

```
<?php

$numbers = array(2,3,4);

foreach ($numbers as &$number){
   $number = $number * 2;
}

// now numbers is $numbers = array(4,6,8);


$var = 'test';
$foo = &var; //now all changes to $foo will be affected to $var, because we've assigned simple pointer 



//Similar to array_push()
function add_key(&$array, $key){
  return $array[$key];
}

//so we don't need to assign returned value from this function
//we just call this one

$array = array('a', 'b');

add_key($array,'c');
//now $array is ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

All benefits of using the references are obvious to me, except the use of "passing function by reference",

Question: When to pass function by reference (I've searched answer here, but still can't grasp this one)
Thanks

Comment: I guess this question belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function that [*returns* by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) -- the term "passing a function by reference" is a bit misleading:

```
function &test(){
    return /* something */;
}
```

The use cases are pretty much the same as for normal references, which is to say not common. For a (contrived) example, consider a function that finds an element in an array:

```
$arr = array(
    array('name' => 'John', 'age' => 20),
    array('name' => 'Mary', 'age' => 30),
);

function &findPerson(&$list, $name) {
    foreach ($list as &$person) {
        if ($person['name'] == $name) {
            return $person;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$john = &findPerson($arr, 'John');
$john['age'] = 21;

print_r($arr); // changing $john produces a visible change here
```

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/9V6Qc).

In the above example, you have encapsulated the code that searches for an item inside a data structure (which in practice could be a lot more complicated than this array) in a function that can be reused. If you intend to use the return value to modify the original structure itself there's no other option than returning a reference from the function (in this specific case you could also have returned an index into the array, but think about structures that do not have indexes, e.g. graphs).

Answer (score 1):

Do you means [Returning References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) ?

A simple example is:

```
function &test(&$a){
  return $a;
}

$a = 10;
$b = &test($a);
$b++;

// here $a became 11
var_dump($a);
```